# How can I move my object to the clicked location?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CreateMagicOnClickArea : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float forceAmount = 10f;
    public GameObject magicPrefab;
    public Transform player;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                Debug.Log(hit.point);
                ApplyForce(hit.point);
            }
        }
    }

    void ApplyForce(Vector3 targetPosition)
    {
        Quaternion forceRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetPosition - transform.position);
        Debug.Log(forceRotation);
        GameObject magicInstance = Instantiate(magicPrefab, player.position, forceRotation);
        Debug.Log(magicInstance);
        Rigidbody magicRigidbody = magicInstance.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        Debug.Log(magicRigidbody);
        magicRigidbody.AddForce(targetPosition - transform.position, ForceMode.Force);
        Debug.Log(magicRigidbody.velocity);
    }
}
```

My code made by 6 AI's and I still didn't understand and made it. I want to instantiate the magic orb and add velocity to click position. When I try it, my orb gone somewhere else and the rotation was not true, it's only going to a fixed position. I couldn't figure it out.

Normalizing the targetPosition-transform.Position. Straight writing the targetPosition for velocity. NavMeshAgent (but it's not working correctly when other agents in way).

Comment: Well i think you summed up the issue, 6 AIs? and you wonder why you dont understand it?  You also havent really articulated what specifically is wrong, other than its wrong.  So you gain a point on the world, where you want the target to go to.   You then make a direction by taking this game object the script is on and looking.  But when you instantiate a magicinstance it is not in the position you're in, its somewhere else - well somewhere else means your direction will be wrong.

Comment: if you don't understand the code then I would suggest stop using AIs and learn to code so you can understand what the AI is generating.  If you do not understand the basics, there is nothing anyone can do to really assist you.  You need to help yourself and get a basic understanding.  This will help in many ways, including being able to ask a question here and supply information that is pertinent to the problem.   You are basically asking someone to fix a block of code you got from an AI and that you yourself do not understand.

Comment: Bro, I already know the basics I meant that I didn't understand the logic.

Comment: a) what others said about AI and coding ;) .. b) rotation that way only works if your orb model/prefab is correctly made in the way that by default it blue forward vector is aligned with the Unity world space forward vector .. c) in your use case it would be easier to directly use `magicRigidbody.velocity = (targetPosition - transform.position). normalized * desiredVelocity;` .. way easier to control and independent of weights

Comment: d) for Instantiate you use `player.position` but for the direction calculations you use `transform.position` .. are those different objects? In that case obviously rotation and move direction will be wrong

Comment: e) the name of that class is extremely misleading .. this doesn't "create" any specific area and also doesn't even apply to a specific area but basically works globally scene wide wherever your raycast hits something - you didn't even filter further

Answer (score -1):

First, what you have to do is to store the mouse's position.

```cs
private float moveSpeed = 5f;
private Vector2 mousePos;

private void Update()
{
     if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
     {
         mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
         transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, mousePos, moveSpeed);
     }
}
```

Comment: This will move **this object** one step per mouse click .. both not what OP is trying to achieve